# Android studio 2.2 unable to open source file due to hc_characterdataindexsizeerrsubstringoffsetgreater

Tags: android, android-studio-2.2

I was working in Android Studio and due to some unknown reason my system(Windows desktop) shutdown. When I restarted the system, started Android Studio, it displayed below warning

> Cannot load settings from file 'C:\Users\Monish.AndroidStudio2.2\config\options\feature.usage.statistics.xml': Error on line 2: Content is not allowed in prolog.
>
> File content will be recreated

And the source file on which I was working changed as below :

[image: Screenshot of project structure showing the issue]

If I try to open it Android Studio stops responding. I am able to open other source files.

If anyone has encountered this issues, I would like to know the reason behind it and how to recover from it.

Comment: you can try opening it with notepad++ and see what is going on inside the file?

Comment: I did that. The file has no issues.

Comment: just restart the android studio using the option in AS. **file->invalid cache/restart**.

Comment: then invalidate cache and restart might help, looks like the `ORCHomeActivity` has renamed itself because of some system error, try starting the android studio without the file and then pasting it back etc

Comment: I deleted the file -> Rebuilt Project -> Added the file back -> Restarted Android Studio with Invalidate and Restart option. It working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the issue got resolved :

1. From Windows Explorer, copy the file to some other directory.
2. Open Android Studio -> Delete the file and Rebuild Project.
3. Paste the file back into the Project in Android Studio -> Rebuild Project.
4. Restart Android Studio with Invalidate and Restart option(File -> Invalidate and Restart).

Don't know the exact reason behind it. As @Max Rockwood suggested, This might be the reason

> The file renamed itself because of some system error.